# Groupby merge values from one dataframe to the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of "words", and I would like to check which words were included, by each person in this dataframe by comparison to a word list key.

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'word': ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'berry'],
    'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})

word_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry', 'grape']
word_df = pd.DataFrame({'word': word_list})
```

For example, person 1 only included `apple`, `orange`, and `pear` and did not include `berry` and `grape`. I know how to pd.merge values but have not been able to successfully map the values of `word_df["word"]` onto something like `df.groupby(["person"]` so that I can check what *each* person chose to include.

Desired output:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'word': ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry', 'grape', 
             'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry', 'grape', 
             'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry', 'grape', 
             'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'berry', 'grape'],
    'count': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
})
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['person', 'word']).unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(columns=word_list, level='word').stack().reset_index()` or with [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) `import janitor ; df.complete('person', {'word': word_list}, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Or by reindexing: `df.set_index(['person', 'word']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['person'].unique(), word_list], names=['person', 'word']), fill_value=0).reset_index()`

Comment: @psychcoder Glad my answer helped. It's worth trying out what mozway suggested though. Mine is total brute force and that looks like it uses purpose built functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance isn't really a concern this looks like it does the trick.

Basically create an intermediate dataframe with all possible person and fruit combinations via cross join. Then use that as the driver, "count" from the outer table will be null if that combination was not found in the original dataframe so coalescing to 0 gets 0's for those.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'word': ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'berry'],
    'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})

word_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry', 'grape']
all_person_word_combos = word_df.merge(df['person'].drop_duplicates(), how='cross')
final_result = (
  all_person_word_combos.
  merge(df, 
        how='left', 
        on=['word', 'person']).
  fillna(0).
  sort_values(['person','word']))
final_result.display()
```

| word | person | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | 1 |
| berry | 1 | 0 |
| grape | 1 | 0 |
| orange | 1 | 1 |
| pear | 1 | 1 |
| apple | 2 | 1 |
| berry | 2 | 0 |
| grape | 2 | 0 |
| orange | 2 | 0 |
| pear | 2 | 0 |
| apple | 3 | 0 |
| berry | 3 | 0 |
| grape | 3 | 1 |
| orange | 3 | 0 |
| pear | 3 | 0 |
| apple | 4 | 1 |
| berry | 4 | 1 |
| grape | 4 | 0 |
| orange | 4 | 1 |
| pear | 4 | 1 |